# Elm submodule's init command not firing

Tags: elm

My app uses Navigate for routing, but, for some reason, the initial http command is not firing for one of the submodules. There could be something wrong in the way commands are wired between parent and child modules, but I could use some help locating the issue. The code and structure is modeled after the elm-taco (https://github.com/ohanhi/elm-taco) example. Below is an excerpt of the relevant parts of the code, and there is no compiler error.

**Main.elm**

```
init : Flags -> Location -> ( AppModel, Cmd Msg )
init flags location =
        (  startModel
        , Http2.get ("localhost:4000/graphql?query=" ++ encoded) HandleLogDataResponse decoder)

update :  Msg -> AppModel -> ( AppModel, Cmd Msg )
update  msg model =
        case msg of
             HandleLogDataResponse webData ->
                 updateLogData model webData
             RouterMsg routerMsg ->
                 updateRouter model routerMsg

updateLogData :  AppModel -> WebData LogData -> ( AppModel, Cmd Msg )
updateLogData  model webData =
    case webData of
        Success logdata ->
            case model.appState of
                NotReady time ->
                    let
                        initTaco =
                            { currentTime = time
                            , logdata = logdata
                            }
                        ( initRouterModel, routerCmd ) =
                            Router.init initTaco model.location
                    in
                        ( { model | appState = Ready initTaco initRouterModel }
                        , Cmd.map RouterMsg routerCmd
                        )

                Ready taco routerModel ->
                    ( { model | appState = Ready (updateTaco taco (UpdateLogData logdata)) routerModel }
                    , Cmd.none
                    )
```

**Router.elm**

```
init : Taco -> Location -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init taco location =
    let 
        ( chatModel, chatCmd) =
               Chat.initModel taco
    in
      ( { chatModel = chatModel
      , route = parseLocation location}
      , Cmd.map ChatMsg chatCmd
      )

update: Msg -> Model -> ( Model,Cmd Msg, TacoUpdate)
update msg model =
    case msg of
        ChatMsg chatMsg ->
            updateChat model chatMsg

updateChat : Model -> Chat.Msg -> (Model, Cmd Msg, TacoUpdate)
updateChat model chatMsg =
    let
        ( nextChatModel, chatCmd, tacoUpdate) =
            Chat.update chatMsg model.chatModel
    in
        ( {model | chatModel = nextChatModel }
        , Cmd.map ChatMsg chatCmd
        , tacoUpdate)
```

**Chat.elm**

```
initModel : Taco -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
initModel taco =
    let
        startModel = { newMessage = ""
                    , messages = taco.messages
                    , response = "Waiting for a response..."
                    , logs = [] 
                    }
        cmd = Http.send FetchHNTopStories request

    in
            ( startModel
            , cmd
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the result of the execution of a command, you need to provide a way for it to get to the runtime.

This is done through `main`. If your `Cmd` do not get to the `main` of the app, they will never be executed.

In the code samples you gave, it is not obvious how the submodule `init` gets to the `main`. Traditionally, the `init` you have in your `Main.elm` should use the `init`s from the submodule, `Cmd.map` the submodule init Cmds and `Cmd.batch` them together with the rest of the main `init` Cmds.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thought Chat.elm's `init` gets to the `main` through Router.elm's `init` and Main.elm's updateLogData which is invoked by Main's init/HandleLogDataResponse. That's basically the structure of the `elm-taco` example, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Oh... sorry about that, I missed the fact that you actually call the init in the Http handler. 

Add some `Debug.log` around the messages and see what's happening. Maybe the `Http2.get` request fails and you never get to the branch where the `Router.init` is evaluated.

Comment: The http request does succeed. I will try Debug. log. thanks

Comment: Any chance you can take a look at the code? https://github.com/puruzio/minimal-taco.git.  In the example code, Chat.elm line 127 has a cmd which I want to be invoked through Router.elm line 46, and then Main.elm line 237. If things work the way I intend, Chat.elm line 193 will Debug.log as such.(but currently it doesn’t)

Comment: The error is in `Main.elm#L66`, you are not passing the cmds.